# Symfony assets: install is not copying ALL files into web

Tags: php, symfony

I have to add some features to a legacy symphony 2 application (version 2.7).

There are several folders under Resources/public in a bundle and after assets:install I found out that only one of the folders (named `img`) gets copied but none of the other folders get copied.

This application is also using assetic to manage the resources.

I grep the all the configuration / source files but still could not figure out why only one folder gets copied by assets:install. Any ideas? Is it possible to do filter folders by name when doing assets:install?

Comment: Did you register the bundle in config.yml file ? 
assetic:
    bundles:

And what's happen when you run assetic:dump command ?